# AJAX asp:UpdatePanel with a asp:Timer never refreshes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

I thought I would experiment with a timer and update panel. I have a simple page that I put an updatepanel control, a label, and a timer.

The "TICK" code updates the label with the current time.
The panel never refreshes. If I put the timer object outside the updatepanel, the whole page refreshes every 1 second. So that tells me that AJAX is in fact working. Just never for the update panel only with the time tag inside the updatepanel. I've tried it with Triggers tags and without. No change. I put a "STOP" directive in the Timer1_Tick sub/code, and when I inspect the value of the lbl1.text value, it does in fact have the updated value, but it just won't render it in the updatepanel. This is why it's a mystery. After several hours of trying anything I could find, I thought I would just ask the experts.

ASPX objects:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnl1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="1000"></asp:Timer>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="THIS IS MY LABEL"  />
            </ContentTemplate>
            
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind (I tried with and without the updPnl1.Update statement), and like I said, if I STOP the code, the value of lbl1.text is actually updated, but no displaying it as such):

```
Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    lbl1.Text = "UpdatePanel1 refreshed at: " & DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
    'Stop    
    updPnl1.Update()
End Sub
```

I tried various examples I've found. I was expecting the lbl1.text to update with the current time.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!
The takeaway from this.
When having a response.write on the page, a timer will work for the entire page but a timer in an UPDATEPANEL will not render at all, although the code behind will function for the timer in the update panel.
Thanks Albert for the helps.

Comment: A response write as we see can and will mess up the headers and informaiton being sent back to the browser. (a update panel is a chunk of the web page, to be updated by the ajax call to the server). If you add headers and/or information in that update panel "response", then that information is sent back to the client side - and it messes up the ajax and code and return values that is ONLY for the UP in question. As I stated, this is not a huge surprise, but still VERY valuable to know. In fact, the timer code in the UP does fire, but tossing in extra information (response.write) breaks this.

Answer (score 0):

Really, in 99% of cases, you don't need nor want a trigger. Why?

Any button, or anything inside of the update panel that cases a post-back works like a regular page lifecycle.

So, if you want the UP to update say due to a button click? Then just make sure the button is inside of the UP and you are 100% fine. (no triggers required).

So, say we want a count down clock of some type.

So, in the update panel, drop in your text boxes (to display the time). Add a button to start, and even one to stop the timer.

And MAKE sure you drop the timer inside of the update panel.

Remember, you can think of a Update Panel as a self contained web page inside of the current page.

Keep in mind while a update panel LOOKS like there is not a post-back, there is! In fact even the page's "load" event fires and triggers each time!

The correct term here is what we call a "partial" page post-back. So, the full page life cycle occurs here, but ONLY for the things inside of the Update Panel.

So, let's drop in three text boxes and a start and stop button inside of a update panel.

Say this:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <div style="padding: 20px">

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <div style="float: left">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblHours" runat="server" Text="Hours" Font-Size="Larger"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtHours" runat="server" Text="0" CssClass="tbox"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>

                <div style="float: left; margin-left: 20px">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMin" runat="server" Text="Minutes" Font-Size="Larger"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMin" runat="server" Text="0" CssClass="tbox"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>

                <div style="float: left; margin-left: 15px">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblsec" runat="server" Text="Seconds" Font-Size="Larger"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSec" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" CssClass="tbox"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>

                <div style="clear: both; height: 15px"></div>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdStart" runat="server" Text="Start" CssClass="btn btn-info" />
                <asp:Button ID="cmdStop" runat="server" Text="Stop" CssClass="btn btn-danger" Style="margin-left: 20px" />

                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblDone" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Enabled="False"></asp:Timer>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>
```

Note how we dropped the timer control inside of the panel. A timer control is actually like a button click - it will "post back" the page based on the interval - it really not much different then dropping a button on the page and clicking it.

Note how I have the timer as disabled to start out.

So, now the user can enter values in to the text boxes, and hit the start button.

So, the start stop code (code behind) is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        txtSec.Text = "5" ' setup a starting value
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub cmdStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdStart.Click

    ' take entered values - convert to time
    Dim MyTime As DateTime
    MyTime = TimeSerial(txtHours.Text, txtMin.Text, txtSec.Text)

    ViewState("MyTime") = MyTime   ' save our time
    Timer1.Interval = 1000  ' upddate every one second
    Timer1.Enabled = True   ' start the timer.
    lblDone.Text = "Started"

    cmdStart.Enabled = False  ' disable our start button

End Sub

Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Dim myTime As DateTime = ViewState("MyTime")

    ' check if we are to stop
    If myTime <= TimeSerial(0, 0, 0) Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False      ' turn off timer
        ' do whatever for end of timer
        lblDone.Text = "Done!"
        cmdStart.Enabled = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim OneSecond As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)

    myTime = myTime - OneSecond
    ' update text boxes
    txtHours.Text = myTime.Hour
    txtMin.Text = myTime.Minute
    txtSec.Text = myTime.Second
    ViewState("MyTime") = myTime

End Sub

Protected Sub cmdStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdStop.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    cmdStart.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

### Edit

Here is the style I used for the three boxes. You can drop in this style for the boxes right after the form tag.

```
        <style>
            .tbox
               {font:x-large bold;border-style:solid;
                height:34px;width:37px;
                text-align:center;
               }
        </style>
```

So, the result now looks like this:

[image]

### Edit 2: Example working code based on question

So the posted markup is this:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnl1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">

        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server"
                Interval="1000"
                Enabled="true"  >
            </asp:Timer>

            <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="THIS IS MY LABEL" />

        </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And code behind is this:

```
Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    lbl1.Text = "UpdatePanel1 refreshed at: " & DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()

End Sub
```

So, now we see this:

[image]

Comment: Excellent input!!
The whole idea that I'm trying is to NOT have to interact with button events and such. Trying to automate the UP from code. Timer seems to work fine outside the UP, but never within the UP.  Seems like it would be straight forward, but we all know how that goes! LOL

Comment: See my edit, you have to set the timer as enabled if you don't need or want a start button. See my edits above.

Comment: Thanks Albert. You always provide help. I copied your response and pasted. Still no joy.
The thing that is interesting is that I can stop the TICK event and display the lbl1.text, and it is refreshed in the code behind. It just doesn't refresh the UP.
I tried moving the timer1 object above the UP code, and it refreshes the whole page.. Strange..

Comment: The example(s) posted work just fine. Perhaps you missing having dropped a script manager onto the page (for the update panels, this is required). So, from toolbox drag + drop in a script manager (drop it in right after the form tag).  My first example markup shows a copy of the script manager, the 2nd posted markup (yours) did not include the script manager - but just drop one in right after the form tag, and then your example code I posted should work.

Comment: Yes. I have a SM. Here is my current code -
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>  

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnl1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">

            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server"
                    Interval="1000"
                    Enabled="true">
                </asp:Timer>

                <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="THIS IS MY LABEL" />

            </ContentTemplate>

        </asp:UpdatePanel>

Comment: It is the strangest thing Albert. I even tried putting the SM right above the TIMER code. Still no joy. What gets me is that the code behind fires on the tick, I can see the value for the label changes to the current time, but it just won't update the label in the UP. What the heck!! LOL.

Comment: Start a new clean web test page. There must be a bunch of details here we are missing. (and don't post code in comments  - no one can read that!!!). Anyway, start a new blank page. Drag in SM, and then between the defaulted on new page the "div", place your content inside. I suggest opening the property sheet for the timer, and then double click on the tick event to wire up the event for the timer.

Comment: That was my next stop Albert. Ugg. OK, thanks for the helps. I'll have to try that and will post the results.. Thanks!

Comment: Albert, While rebuilding the new page, and adding objects, I found that having a "response.write" on the page breaks the timer from working within the UP. Strange.

Comment: Not a total surprise, since a UP is a chunk or part of the page, but response write is going to be sent back to the whole browser and mess this up. So, a surprise? A bit, but not a huge one. I mean, even with a ajax call made by pure JavaScript (calling a webmethod on that page), I am rather confident that a response write going to be included in the response and mess up the ajax call. At least we know this now, but as noted, often it helps to post your code that don't work, and include more of it. As I stated, a update panel is not 100% ajax call, since page load event fires each time.

Comment: The final image in this post is a dark grey box - I assume that was not the intent, and the image has become broken.

Comment: Actually, give it time - it is a animated gif - it should work and look just fine. You not spending enough time and taking care in your edits, but it's still appreciated. Do look and spend more time - you see the image should look ok.